# How do I convert a datetime column in database from UTC to PST using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database called dialogqa and table called dbo.devicelog with one of the column called LogDateTime in UTC DateTime format. I want to convert the UTC DateTime format into PST format.

However, I already have a Select query in the beginning and a result generated with the code:

```
Select * from DeviceLog where EnergyConsumed <= 10000 and LogDateTime between '2018-01-15' and '2018-01-18'
```

order by LogDateTime ASC;

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFcqX.png)

How can I merge the UTC -> PST code to the above so the final result shows the LogDateTime format -8 hours?

Sorry I'm new to SQL query and I hope the question makes sense.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you heard of Google????  Google your title and you'll find tons of example.  It's part of programmer job to do some research.

Comment: A specific answer was posted to a specific question which otherwise would be difficult to google. Google search result did return separate solutions but to join them together required more learning time instead. I'm not a programmer but thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use DateAdd function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql

e.g.

```
Select *, dateadd(hour, -8, LogDateTime) from DeviceLog where EnergyConsumed <= 10000 and dateadd(hour, -8, LogDateTime) between '2018-01-15' and '2018-01-18'
```

Comment: Except when the date range is inside, or crosses, Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding dateadd(hour, -8 LogDateTime) at the end of the select statement instead of right after select *, and SQL was giving me an error. This is a very specific answer to my question.

Comment: Yep. DST is not handled but this specific query will return the correct result for PST.